# Glissando without a final note too long

Tags: lilypond, glissando

I've tried different methods to have a glissando without a final note. The problem is that the glissando sign is too long whatever the hidden note is. I need a short glissando sign. Is that possible?

Here is a minimal code:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

\header {
  % Remove default LilyPond tagline
  tagline = ##f
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
  }
}

global = {
\key gf \major
  \override Glissando.style = #'trill
  \hide Staff.BarLine
}
\relative c' {
\global 
ef8 ef4 f8 f4 ef8 f8
gf2 \glissando
af2. \glissando
gf4.. gf16
gf2. \glissando \hideNotes d16 \unHideNotes
\bar "||"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the code you are using?  Is the glissando too long horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: In addition to the above, please indicate the instrument(s) involve.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what you are trying to achieve without some kind of image/drawing.

I guess that you want the final note to take up no metrical time in the bar, if so you probably want to use a hidden grace note:

```
    \afterGrace gf2\glissando { \hideNotes af8 \unHideNotes }
```

### Update

Now that you have posted the code that you are working with, it seems like there is a problem with the timing translator.  I think you should be using a cadenza instead of just hiding the bar lines.

Try something like this:

```
    \cadenzaOn
    ef8 ef4 f8 f4 ef8 f8
    \afterGrace gf2\glissando { \hideNotes af8 \unHideNotes }
    \afterGrace af2.\glissando { \hideNotes gf8 \unHideNotes }
    gf4.. gf16
    \afterGrace gf2.\glissando { \hideNotes d8 \unHideNotes }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a note in a hidden voice to anchor the end of the gliss.

Comment: From the OP: "the glissando sign is too long whatever the hidden note is"